# Retinex algorithm implementation

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing, image-enhancement

I need to implement [Single Scale retinex and multiscale retinex algorithm](http://web.mit.edu/persci/people/yzli/9.35/Retinex.pdf) in C#,
I searched a bit but couldn't find any useful practice projects and artilces with code 
 
As I understood correctly I should:

1. Convert RGB to YUV
2. Blur the image using Gaussian blur filter
3. Use I'(x, y) = 255*log10( I(x, y)/G(x, y) ) + 127.5
   I - is illumination, G - Gaussian kernel, I' - the result image
4. Сonvert back YUV to RGB

This code is not working correctly

```
 public static Image<Bgr, byte> SingleScaleRetinex(this Image<Bgr, byte> img, int gaussianKernelSize, double sigma)
            {
                var radius = gaussianKernelSize / 2;
                var kernelSize = 2 * radius + 1;

                var ycc = img.Convert<Ycc, byte>();

                var sum = 0f;
                var gaussKernel = new float[kernelSize * kernelSize];
                for (int i = -radius, k = 0; i <= radius; i++, k++)
                {
                    for (int j = -radius; j <= radius; j++)
                    {
                        var val = (float)Math.Exp(-(i * i + j * j) / (sigma * sigma));
                        gaussKernel[k] = val;
                        sum += val;
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < gaussKernel.Length; i++)
                    gaussKernel[i] /= sum;

                var gray = new Image<Gray, byte>(ycc.Size);
                CvInvoke.cvSetImageCOI(ycc, 1);
                CvInvoke.cvCopy(ycc, gray, IntPtr.Zero);

                // Размеры изображения
                var width = img.Width;
                var height = img.Height;

                var bmp = gray.Bitmap;
                var bitmapData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, gray.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

                unsafe
                {
                    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
                    {
                        var row = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0 + y * bitmapData.Stride;
                        for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
                        {
                            var color = row + x;

                            float val = 0;

                            for (int i = -radius, k = 0; i <= radius; i++, k++)
                            {
                                var ii = y + i;
                                if (ii < 0) ii = 0; if (ii >= height) ii = height - 1;

                                var row2 = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0 + ii * bitmapData.Stride;
                                for (int j = -radius; j <= radius; j++)
                                {
                                    var jj = x + j;
                                    if (jj < 0) jj = 0; if (jj >= width) jj = width - 1;

                                    val += *(row2 + jj) * gaussKernel[k];

                                }
                            }

                            var newColor = 127.5 + 255 * Math.Log(*color / val);
                            if (newColor > 255)
                                newColor = 255;
                            else if (newColor < 0)
                                newColor = 0;
                            *color = (byte)newColor;
                        }
                    }
                }
                bmp.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

                CvInvoke.cvCopy(gray, ycc, IntPtr.Zero);
                CvInvoke.cvSetImageCOI(ycc, 0);

                return ycc.Convert<Bgr, byte>();

            }
```

Comment: Have you fixed your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at:
http://www.fer.unizg.hr/ipg/resources/color_constancy

These algorithms are modifications of the Retinex algorithm (with speed improvement) although the author gave them  funny names :)

There is a full source code (C++, but it is written very nicely).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for necro-posting, but it seems that there's a mistake in step 3 of your procedure that can mislead someone passing by.

In order to apply the correction, you want to divide source image by Gauss-filtered copy of it, not the Gaussian kernel itself. Approximately, in pseudo-code:

```
I_filtered(x,y) = G(x,y) * I(x,y)
I'(x,y) = log(I(x,y) / I_filtered(x,y))
```

And then apply casting of `I'(x,y)` to required numeric type (`uint8`, as I can refer from original post).

More on that topic can be found in [this paper](http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2014/107/article.pdf):

> `Ri(x, y) = log(Ii(x, y)) − log(Ii(x, y) ∗ F(x, y))`
>
> where `Ii`
>   is the input image on the i-th color channel, `Ri`
>   is the retinex output image on the i-th
>   channel and `F` is the normalized surround function.
>   .

Comment: Please include the relevant parts from the link in your paper.

Comment: Updated the comment.